# Solve non-linear system of four variable

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have the following nonlinear system:

\begin{align}
2x-2a-b&=0\\
2y-a+b&=0\\
a(-2x-2y-1)&=0\\
b(-x+y+4)&=0\\
a, b &\geq 0
\end{align}

We can see the solutions [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20system%20%7B2x-2a-b%3D0;%202y-a%2Bb%3D0;%20a(-2x-2y-1)%3D0;%20b(-x%2By%2B4)%3D0%7D).

My question is - how can I solve this system as simply as possible "on paper"?

Comment: My first move would be to add the first 2 question and substitute x+y into the 3rd equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Sum two first equations and get:

$$2x+2y=3a \quad (1)$$

Plug it in the third equation:

$$a(-3a-1)=0 \rightarrow a=0 \quad \text{or} \quad a=-1/3 \quad (2)$$

Subtract two first equations and get:

$$x-y=\frac{a+2b}{2} \quad (3)$$

Plug it in the fourth equation:

$$b\left(-\frac{a+2b}{2}+4\right)=0 \rightarrow b=0 \quad \text{or} \quad a+2b=8 \quad (4)$$

Using $(2)$ and $(4)$ you can find $a$ and $b$. Then back to $(1)$ and $(3)$ and find $x$ and $y$.

Can you finish?